# How to deal with missing branches in Unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am trying to wrap up an assignment in Java and I am having one hell of a time getting my overridden `equals` method to work properly.

I have an item class that takes 1 of 2 constructors, the first takes 2 values and the second takes 4. My `equals` method works properly only with an `Item` created with the 4 parameter constructor. I am unsure how to deal with `Items` that have only 2 of the 4 parameters.

Here is what I have:

1. I start with testing for `null` and for both to be of the same class.
2. If good I cast to an Item object for more specific testing.
3. If my coding is right I should then be testing for the 2 values that both constructors use. However I am unsure if I am going about this right for testing if the object contains the other two parameters.

My Unit test for equals passes when using it with a 4 parameter `Item`, but fails with a 2 parameter `Item`.

I searched here and elsewhere (I usually find my answers here and have never had to ask a question), but nothing helped me with this specific issue. Since I have never had to ask a question please let me know what additional information/code you need from me.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object theOther) {
    boolean result = false;
    if ((theOther != null) && (theOther.getClass() == this.getClass())) {
        final Item otherItem = (Item) theOther;
        if (otherItem.myItemName.equals(this.myItemName)
            && otherItem.myItemPrice.equals(this.myItemPrice)) { 
            if (otherItem.myItemBulkQuantity != 0 
                            && !otherItem.myItemBulkPrice.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)) {
                result = otherItem.myItemBulkPrice.equals(this.myItemBulkPrice)
                    && otherItem.myItemBulkQuantity == this.myItemBulkQuantity;                   
            } 
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here are my Unit Tests:

```
/**
 * Test method for bulk quantities.
 */
@Test
public void testEqualsObjectWithBulkQuantities() {
    myItem = new Item(ITEM_TEST_NAME, new BigDecimal(ITEM_TEST_PRICE), 6, 
                      new BigDecimal(ITEM_TEST_BULK_PRICE));
    final Item thisNextItem = new Item(ITEM_TEST_NAME, new BigDecimal(ITEM_TEST_PRICE), 6, 
                               new BigDecimal(ITEM_TEST_BULK_PRICE));
    assertEquals(true, myItem.equals(thisNextItem));
}

/**
 * Test method for equals method with no bulk quantity.
 */
@Test
public void testEqualsObjectNoBulkQuantities() {
    myItem = new Item(ITEM_TEST_NAME, new BigDecimal(ITEM_TEST_PRICE));
    final Item thisNextItem = new Item(ITEM_TEST_NAME, new BigDecimal(ITEM_TEST_PRICE));
    assertEquals(true, myItem.equals(thisNextItem));
}
```

Code for constructors below

```
public Item(final String theName, final BigDecimal thePrice) {

    myItemName = theName;

    myItemPrice = thePrice;

    myItemBulkPrice = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    myItemBulkQuantity = 0;

}

/**
 * Creates a new item with 4 parameters.
 * 
 * @param theName The name of the item.
 * @param thePrice The price of the item.
 * @param theBulkQuantity The bulk quantity of the item.
 * @param theBulkPrice The price of the item using a bulk quantity.
 */
public Item(final String theName, final BigDecimal thePrice, final int theBulkQuantity,
            final BigDecimal theBulkPrice) {

    myItemName = theName;

    myItemPrice = thePrice;

    myItemBulkQuantity = theBulkQuantity;

    myItemBulkPrice = theBulkPrice;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused... What does the `equals()` method have to do with constructors?  All this code should be doing is testing if two instances are logically equal.  It wouldn't matter how either of those instances were originally created.  How exactly is this failing?  And what are you trying to fix, the `equals()` method, the unit test (not shown), or the constructors (not shown)?

Comment: Exactly, how do I setup this method so it knows when to test for just 2 parameters or all 4? I apologize I am horrible at explanations, I don't know what happens with the other 2 parameters if they are not set in the constructor. The Item class is literally the class I built and not an arbitrary name.

Comment: here are my Unit tests for my equals method

Comment: That's my point, this method shouldn't *care* about the different constructors.  Exactly how does this method fail when one constructor is used instead of another?  The `equals()` method has, literally, *nothing* to do with the constructors.  Maybe the constructors aren't setting default values for class-level members and this method assumes they do?

Comment: Added my Tests, the first test passes perfectly fine but the second fails and I am unsure why. I have default values of 0 set if they are not set in the constructor so that is what I am testing for in my equals method for the other 2 parameter.

Comment: This sounds like a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with a debugger.  With that you can step through the runtime behavior of the code and examine the logic as it executes and what the runtime values of the variables are.  That's going to be your first step in determining why this is failing, which is a necessary step before correcting that failure.

Comment: Very true lol. I am mainly a c# programmer and I know the VS debugger like the back of my hand, good place to start. This is definitely a logic error somewhere...

Comment: Can you share the code for `Item`'s constructors please?

Comment: ECLemma keeps telling me there are branches missed during my Unit Testing, this confuses me as I get a true result back when my first test of the equals method runs so it has to run through all the tests to get that result. I must not understand the "missed branches" statement

Comment: Constructors added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the following:

```
if (otherItem.myItemName.equals(this.myItemName)
        && otherItem.myItemPrice.equals(this.myItemPrice)) { 
        if (otherItem.myItemBulkQuantity != 0 
                        && !otherItem.myItemBulkPrice.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)) {
            result = otherItem.myItemBulkPrice.equals(this.myItemBulkPrice)
                && otherItem.myItemBulkQuantity == this.myItemBulkQuantity;                   
        } 
}
```

if the two parameters are equal, but the other two not, your result will not be set, and you initialized it with false, so it will return false! You have to implement an else to the second if, and set something like

```
result = otherItem.myItemName.equals(this.myItemName)
            && otherItem.myItemPrice.equals(this.myItemPrice)
```

or directly result = true, because you checked it in the first if!

Comment: HA! wow totally missed that, I would always get a failure without that else statement. NICE FIND thank you thank you. Guess my eyes have started to gloss over between the various classes this program has. Imagine that put in the else statement and she shows green all through :)

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me that this doesn't really answer the question but I fear I can't sleep well tonight without saying a word about the `if` pyramid.

Chaining `ifs` without `elses` is like the boolean `&&`:

```
 if ( this is true )
   // AND
   if ( this is true )
     thisIsApplied()
```

Which leads to the more readable/comprehensible/easy-documentable/quick-nothing-forgotten-checkable/debuggable/...:

```
return
  theOther != null && 
  theOther.getClass() == getClass() &&

  // check names' and prices' equality
  otherItem.myItemName.equals( myItemName ) &&
  otherItem.myItemPrice.equals( myItemPrice ) &&

  // check bulk quantities and prices for not being zero       
  otherItem.myItemBulkQuantity != 0 &&
  !otherItem.myItemBulkPrice.equals( BigDecimal.ZERO ) &&

  // check bulk quantities and prices for equality 
  otherItem.myItemBulkQuantity == myItemBulkQuantity &&
  otherItem.myItemBulkPrice.equals( myItemBulkPrice );
```